# jquery script linking beginner

Tags: jquery, html

im having a hard time getting my script to load, not sure if its due to my noob-ness or something else.

here's what i have to link to the script

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="testbitad.css"/>
<script src="testscript.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

the testscript.js is in the same folder as the html, here the script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main-content").accordion();
})
```

Comment: load jquery assets first, your script relies on jquery.

Answer (score 4):

Your script loading order isn't right.

First load the jquery, then jquey.UI and at the end your scripts.

Then do a test:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert("it works");
});
```

Comment: This can easily be checked with a debugger, you will see a JavasScript error with $ is undefined.

Comment: @Jonathan if you have a debugger

Comment: Yeah, but someone might not have it if they don't know what it is.

Comment: I have a debugger.....but for some reason I always just alert('test');  lol.....does that make me lazy?  or just stupid....hahahha

Comment: Neither, but you might just want to press F12 next time and read the error. Lot less effort than posting on a forum ;)

Comment: Im not the OP..lol  But I do agree :)

Comment: awesome, now the script loads but i still have problem with my code. should i even use acorrdion? the effect i want is to have a section expand after someone click on a button.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange like this,  all scripts using Jquery have to come AFTER jquery, as they have dependancies on it...

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="testbitad.css"/>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="testscript.js"></script>
```

And for kicks, to make sure its loading properly add an alert for fun...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 alert('Loaded...booyah!');
 $("#main-content").accordion();
});
```

Also...once the site goes live, you'll wanna change to this...(remove http: off google librarires)

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="testbitad.css"/>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="testscript.js"></script>
```